# How to display read-only information on a webpart? ReadOnly TextField or Label?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, best-practices, fabric

I wonder if the Office-UI Fabric `Label` should only be used to label a field, like a `TextField`.

Should read-only data be displayed in `TextField` with `contentEditable={ false }` and `readOnly={ true }`?

Or should a `Label` be used to display read-only information?

The [TextField documentation](https://dev.office.com/fabric#/components/textfield) states

> Use the TextField to accept data input on a form or page.

I think a `Label` would be better performance as well. I just wonder if it violates good PnP?

For shipped/packaged webparts, e.g. not running on a workbench, a colon (:) is automatically appended. Does that state that a `Label` should only label something else?